# Two-variable limit, quotient of polynomials

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I'm trying to evaluate the following limit,
$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^3-y^2}{x^2-y} $$
which I think it doesn't exist, since for the curve $\alpha :[0,1]\to \mathbb R^2$, $\alpha(t) = (t, t^2)$ it isn't well defined, and if the limit exists it is because for every continuous curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb R^2$ such that $\gamma(0) = (0,0)$ and $\gamma(t) \neq (0,0)$ for all $t\neq 0$, and $\lim_{t\downarrow 0} f(\gamma(t)) = 0.$  Is that correct? How would you evaluate the limit? Any hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't take that curve since the function is not defined there. When you calculate the limit you can go only through the domain of that function. In this case, this parabola ($y=x^2$) is not in the domain.

Comment: Thanks @Poppy, you have confirmed what i thought

Comment: You can take another curve or a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If you take $\alpha(t)=(t^2,t^3)$ you get that if the limit exists it must be zero.

Comment: @Poppy I already got that, also for every $(t,\lambda t)$... but I am nearly sure that it doesn't exist

Comment: Hm... I tried some things, but nothing worked. Is this some homework or exam question?

Comment: @Poppy No. A proposition of a classmate

Comment: I don't think a "polynomial thing" is going to solve this. Try $(x, \sin{x})$ and then L'Hospital rule several times (I suppose). Does it give something?

Comment: @Poppy Sure, I have come to the same conclusion. I'll give a try with things like that

Comment: Let me know, I am interested if it works :)

Comment: @Poppy Mmm, probably $\gamma(t) = (\sin(t),\sin(t^2))$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(x,y)=(x^3-y^2)/(x^2-y)$ then $f(t,t^2+t)=t(t^2+t+1)$ while $f(t,t^2+t^3)=t^3+2t^2+t-1.$ So as $t \to 0$ one of them goes to $0$ and the other goes to $-1$.

Comment: Thanks. Great work. Would be too much to ask how did you get to that curve $(t,t^2+t^3)$

Comment: @ua11 I took the $y=x^2$ curve (not allowed since it makes denominator zero) and perturbed it by adding the extra $t$ power of $t$ versus $t^3$, which go to zero at very different rates.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got $(\sin t, \sin t^2)$, but I'm not sure if it is completely right.

Comment: @ua11 That's hard to check, if you mean $\sin(t^2)$ rather than $(\sin t)^2$ [the latter gives undefined anyway...]

Comment: I meant $\sin(t^2)$

Comment: @ua11 Your choice seems numerically to give the limit $\pm \infty$ depending on which side of $0$ is approached by $t$.

Comment: Got it with Mathematica. It is valid also, right? Thanks for everything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12767/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-ua11)